# What could this Read Access violation Exception be due to?

Tags: c++, access-violation

My program crashes and a dialog box shows

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x3aaf1aea (pmsqlsrv.dll) in java.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0x3ac60880."
```

The statement shown as causing the crash is

```
m_pDatabase->m_pIDBCreateCommand->CreateCommand();
```

In the watch window,

```
"this" pointer value for the containing object is 0x7395fcaf
m_pDatabase                                    is 0xffff8810 (does it look like a valid address?)
m_pDatabase->m_pIDBCreateCommand               CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

The addresses shown in the crash dialog box - 0xC0000005 and 0x3ac60880 I don't know what they are. Does this mean that the dll (pmsqlsrv.dll) itself is corrupted and the crash is in reading the code segment rather than in accessing the data?

Comment: It is likely that one of the pointers m_pDatabase, or m_pIDBCreateCommand is not pointing to where you think it is, but there's not nearly enough information in the question to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

In 32 bit Windows the address `0xC0000000` and above are reserved for the kernel. Usually the kernel address space starts even at `0x80000000`. So that address indeed doesn't look healthy.

Answer (score 0):

0xC0000005 is the address of the "segment fault" interrupt exception handler of the kernel: it is invoked when trying to access a memory address not belonging to your process.

Your `m_pDatabase` points to 0xffff8810 (very strange memory address: points to the static data area ... was it initialized properly?)
Since it is most likely not a valid address, it contains some meaningless values that makes the program believe that there is something in `m_pIDBCreateCommand` (probably a random value) trough wich get the address for the function to call. This makes it -after two or three indirection- to access memory outside its process boundaries.

Give a look on how m_pDatabase is initialized, assigned and changed thorough your program.

Comment: The "this" object itself seems invalid, as many of its members are shown as "<Bad Ptr>" in the watch window. But the memory error detection tool shows no error prior to the crash point, only a "Invalid read" at the crash point. What approach could I take to find how the pointer becomes invalid? I tried writing the this pointer value to a file just before the statement that is crashing, but it won't even write to the file even though the control should have passed through those lines.

Comment: The problem is that the this object has invalid content, but its address fits your process boundaries. hence form the memory detection tool it has the full right to exist.
It has been probably overwritten by something else during a buffer overrun a stack unwinding. Not easy to detect those situations.
If you can set a breakpoint on values, try to identify an execution point where the object itself is valid, and check when it changes.